# ROS Image subscriber - window popup does not appear

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, ros, subscriber

I am following image subscribe tutorial on official ROS page. when I run my_subscriber no window popup appears. I type -

```
rosrun image_transport_tutorial my_subscriber
```

output is -

```
init done
opengl support available
```

And then nothing happens. (even the output "init done" is unexplained because there is not output line in my_subscriber.cpp)

I am following this tutorial - [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/ExaminingImagePublisherSubscriber)

I have roscore and rosrun image_transport_tutorial my_publisher pathtofile already running in dofferent terminals.
I checked that publisher is publishing by running command

```
rostopic list -v
```

my_subscriber file has the following contents -

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  try
  {
    cv::imshow("view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout<<"kapil";
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  cv::namedWindow("view");
  cv::startWindowThread();
  image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("camera/image", 1, imageCallback);
  ros::spin();
  cv::destroyWindow("view");
}
```

Solved : I added waitKey function in the try block as suggested in one of the answers.

```
cv::waitKey(30);
```

Comment: Did you check if the topic camera/image is publishing something? Run this: $ rostopic list -v

Comment: yes... i checked.. it is publishing. here is the output - 
Published topics:
..
 * /camera/image [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 publisher
 
Subscribed topics:
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
 * /camera/image [sensor_msgs/Image] 1 subscriber

Comment: if you have the package image_view install, try the following: $rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image . Tell me what you got.

Comment: I have it installed. it is not working. this is the output - [ INFO] [1425987943.187518428]: Using transport "raw"
init done 
opengl support available 

(image_view:12714): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkWidget'

(image_view:12714): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type '(null)'

(image_view:12714): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

Comment: try this: $rostopic echo /camera/image . Tell me what you get.

Comment: I tried rostopic echo /camera/image. I am getting lots of numbers coming very fast... filling my terminal... i guess these are the camera pixel output.

Comment: It looks like some libraries are missing. Try this: sudo apt-get install ros-[your ros distro here]-theora-image-transport

Comment: tried it... no luck... :( .. it was already upgraded... I cant resolve the problem... i guess there is a problem in the subscriber.. i tried $rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph . it was showing correct publisher, topic and subscriber.. as expected.

Comment: I just tried the tutorial on my machine with ROS indigo installed. Everything works fine.

Comment: Somebody else have the same problem [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/83). What's the configuration of your machine? Which ubuntu? Which ros distro?

Comment: I am using ros-indigo, ubuntu 14.04. my machine is intel i5, 4gb ram....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comment to [this answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/27787/imshow-and-waitkey/?answer=27840#post-id-27840), using `cv::startWindowThread()` does not always work. Maybe this is the issue in your case.

Try to add `cv::waitKey(10)` after `cv::imshow` instead. This will wait for some key press for 10 milliseconds, giving the window time to show the image.
(This always seemed to me like a dirty hack, but it is the common way to show images in OpenCV...)